# Postfix not rewriting sender

Tags: email, postfix

I'm trying to setup postfix to wildcard forward all incoming e-mail for domain A to domain B, i.e. user1@domainA.com is forwarded to user1@domainB.com.

I've done this with virtual_alias:

From main.cf

`virtual_alias_domains = domainA.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`

in /etc/postfix/virtual

`@domainA.com      @domainB.com`

This seem to work ok except for one problem. If the sender domain has SPF setup, the mail server at domainB.com will naturally complain.

I've been trying to configure postfix to rewrite the FROM address to overcome this. I used sender_canonical_maps in various ways, both statically, with a regexp wildcard map and finally also with postsrsd (which is overkill since I don't care about replies).

Right now I am using:

`sender_canonical_maps = static:postmaster@domainA.com`

In all cases, the problem seems to be the same. When looking at the log, it seems like the sender is changed but when looking at the actual mail headers on the receiving server it is not.

Here is an excerpt from mail.log when trying to send an e-mail from gmail.

`Aug 23 01:06:28 www postfix/smtpd[23960]: connect from mail-lf0-f49.google.com[209.85.215.49]
Aug 23 01:06:28 www postfix/smtpd[23960]: 35146A2957: client=mail-lf0-f49.google.com[209.85.215.49]
Aug 23 01:06:28 www postfix/cleanup[23965]: 35146A2957: message-id=<CAAGGpbAn=odN7E-hnbVyHjtiF3Bzk8AN-27UAix7w_03JjExCA@mail.gmail.com>
Aug 23 01:06:28 www postfix/qmgr[23957]: 35146A2957: from=<postmaster@domainA.com>, size=2493, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 23 01:06:28 www postfix/smtpd[23960]: disconnect from mail-lf0-f49.google.com[209.85.215.49]
Aug 23 01:06:29 www postfix/smtp[23966]: 35146A2957: to=<user1@domainB.com>, orig_to=<user1@domainA.com>, relay=mx.domainB.com[130.237.32.10]:25, delay=0.81, delays=0.07/0.01/0.01/0.73, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 0D442240110)
Aug 23 01:06:29 www postfix/qmgr[23957]: 35146A2957: removed`

- Am I correct in my assessment that the sender is identified and replaced?
- Am I correct that this for some reason doesn't actually change the FROM header?
- How can I correct this?

Btw, I'm simply trying to accomplish this wildcard forwarding and if there is any other mail server software which makes this simpler, I'll happily change.

Comment: Are you the admin of both servers? In which case you could simply whitelist the first server IP from SPF checking in the second server. Or you will have to use SRS for postfix which I have not used. But search google and you will be able to find how to implement SRS on postfix.

Comment: I am not admin on domainB. I did install postsrsd and configured that but it seems like it's still not rewriting the from header and thus failing SPF.